# Minimum size of the largest clique in any graph

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find the minimum size of the largest clique in any graph which has $V$ nodes and $E$ edges (the same as this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1279241/50804))

This looks like an application of [Turan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem):

> Let G be any graph with n vertices, such that G is Kr+1 -free. Then
>   the number of edges in G is at most:
>   [image]

Solving the inequality, I got the $$r \leq \frac{V^2}{V^2 - 2E}$$.

The formula works correctly but for a couple of examples I get wrong answers:

```
V, E, formula, answer
19, 166, 13, 14 
34, 549, 20, 22
49, 1108, 13, 14
38, 688, 22, 23
```

So what is wrong with my formula?

Comment: Is there any relationship between $N$, $M$ and $V$, $E$?

Comment: @joriki N is the number of vertices in a wiki formula. E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices

Comment: The question should use consistent notation. Why introduce $N$ and $M$ as the numbers of nodes and edges and then use other symbols instead?

Comment: @joriki sorry, it was not wise. Changed that

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is the direction of the inequality. The theorem only provides a lower bound on the minimum size of a maximal clique, not an upper bound.

Comment: Any approach you would have taken to solve the problem?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Not really. Since the proof of Turan's theorem is already rather non-trivial and it seems to be a rather tight bound, I would expect it to be rather difficult to improve on it.